# Forcing the user to type an int in Java - Receiving an unclear Error

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a method that only accepts an int as a valid answer, and once it receives it it returns it.

```
public class Application {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int usersInt = getIntInput();
    }

    public static int getIntInput(){
        int userInt;
        boolean success = false;
        while (!success){
            try {
                userInt = sc.nextInt();
                success = true; 
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Please type an int");
            }
        }
        return userInt;  // ERROR
    }
}
```

I receive an error:

```
The local varaible userInt May not have been initialized.
```

I thought that until the user types an int we will continue to receive an error, success won't receive true, and the while loop will continue to prompt the user to type an int. Is there any problem with my logic?

Comment: Your logic is fine, but the compiler isn't as smart as you. Just initialize `userInt` with a dummy value.

Comment: I would have rather used a `do while` instead of while

Comment: For future reference: BlockQuote format is for quoting text.  Error messages and stack traces should be formatted as `code` (indent everything 4 spaces).  Using blockquote for stack traces messes up the line breaks and indentation and makes them very hard to read.  In this particular case it made no difference but please get in the habit of not using blockquote for messages.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Integer type instead of int, which you can then check for null in your caller to see if any number was entered at all. You can then initialise your `userInt` in `getIntInput` to `null`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer usersInt = getIntInput();
}

public static Integer getIntInput(){
    Integer userInt = null; // Initialise the variable.
    boolean success = false;
    while (!success){
        try {
            userInt = sc.nextInt();
            success = true; 
        } catch (Exception e){
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please type an int");
        }
    }
    return userInt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to run the application, but when entering a char, the message "Please type an int" was printed to the screen infinitely (until closing the app).

Comment: I added a line in my answer: `sc.nextLine();` to wait for the next line.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem in your code is that you are using uninitialized local variable.

**Note:** Java compiler is not *enough intelligent* to figure out that the `userInt` object will be initialize inside loop for sure.

Following are some options to correct your code:

- Just change the line `int userInt;` to `int userInt = 0;` and add line `sc.nextLine();` or `sc.next()` in `catch-block`(to *flush `stdin`*, otherwise it will go in infinite loop printing message `Please type an int`). **OR**
- Change your code as following:

  ```
  public class Application {
      static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int usersInt = getIntInput();

      }

      public static int getIntInput(){
          while (true){
              try {
                  return sc.nextInt();
              } catch (Exception e){
                  System.out.println("Please type an int");
                  sc.nextLine();
              }
          } 
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I tried it I got an error: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from null to int".

Comment: @Ben One addition, Don't forget to _flush `stdin`_ in `catch-block`.

Comment: This is an excellent alternative. But there is no need for ```boolean success```. We can change the while loop  to ```while(true)``` and save a line of code.

Comment: In case our try loop succeeds, we need to flush. Otherwise we will have problems with user Input later on. I suggested an edit accordingly.

Comment: @Ben Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165103/discussion-between-cse-and-ben).

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the userInt variable outside the while loop, and initializing the value of it inside the loop. As far as the compiler is concerned the loop may not run and userInt may not be given a value by the time it is returned at the end of the function call. So it throws out the error "The local variable userInt may not have been initialized" to try to help you find a potential error that could cause users an issue with the program.

Initializing the variable with a default value can of course help, but can also limit input by preventing that value from being useful as input. If the value is naturally limited though and the limit does not include the minimum and maximum values of the binary representation that you're using to store the value then a value outside the range can be used as the default value. Such as needing users to input a number that's 1 or higher and using 0 as the default for when there is no input given.

In the case that you do need the entire range of values you can instead use a Boolean flag and return both it and the user's input value. Then in the handler when you get input from a user set the flag as needed and test in the calling function to see that there was user input received.